# How would you show a file with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

There is an epic lack of PHP cURL love on the Internet for beginners like me. I was wondering how to use cURL to download & display an ICS file (They're plain text to me...) in my PHP code. Unless `fopen()` is 1,000 times easier, I'd like to stick with cURL for this one.

Comment: +1 - good question. thumbs up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your webserver allows it, `file_get_contents()` is even easier.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/path/to/your/file.ics');
```

If you can not open URLs with `file_get_contents()` check out all the stuff on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+curl), which I believe should be fine for a beginner.

Comment: COOL! "Allows it?" I'm on slicehost man, it allows anything I want it too!

Comment: Just remember to add the proper `Content-Type` header before you echo the statement, otherwise you will just get plain text.

Comment: The entire point of the proxy was plain text actually. I needed to parse the ics with Javascript. I know it sounds crazy ;D

Answer (score 0):

If remote `file_get_contents` is not enabled, cURL can indeed do this.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/file.ics');

// this is the key option - sets curl_exec to return the HTTP response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$file_contents = curl_exec($curl);
```